# Invoking Angular Component from a ASP.NET Core Service which is Registered as a Redirect URI from External Source

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, callback

I am new to angular. I am developing an `ASP.NET Core` application with `angular` where I redirect to an external `Microsoft SSO` page from my angular component. I have registered a service endpoint in my ASP.NET Core as a redirect URI from the Microsoft SSO page. Now I want to return the results from my service endpoint(which I registered as a redirect URI from my Microsoft SSO) back to the `angular component`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it have callback function when the angular redirects to external page? But a better way is to redirect to angular with carrying results.

Comment: Redirection url is configured within your SSO ( in the client configuration if you're using Identity Server for instance)

Comment: @Karney. How can we set the angular route as a callback URL?